# MYSQL #1045 error on mac os x 10.9 (with my password)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I was using ubuntu before i have bought my macbook pro. And today i started to use this computer.

Now, I did everything to install php, apache and mysql

http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks

But, when i try to connect mysql (localhost/~mehmet/phpMyAdmin/) by phpmyadmin i get this error:

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I think, I have already set my mysql password but it does not work fine.

So, I need to set some settings maybe, please help me..

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac, the location of the MySQL socket file isn't generally where PHP expects it to be.

From the Terminal, can you use `mysql -u root -p`? If so, type `status;` to see how it's connecting (`Connection` and `UNIX socket` are the values we're interested in). If Connection is TCP/IP, you can change your phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php` to add the [`connect_type`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_connect_type) directive, setting it to 'tcp'. If it's socket, you can look at the UNIX socket path and use that [value in `config.inc.php`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_socket).

If you're really ambitious, you can edit your php.ini to reflect the proper path. If you're slightly less ambitious, you may wish to make a symlink from where the socket actually lives to where PHP expects it to live. A cursory Google search should help with both of those options.